# What makes debian different from other variants given they have same kernel?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, embedded, root-filesystem, yocto

In the recent project we have been asked to create a debain based system for a SOC. Doing some gooogling I did find guides that point to ways to use yocto to create a debian system [1]. But then I also came across steps to create debian root filesystem using multistrap[2] and it worked (just had to give list of packages in config file).

After going through all this I am unable to bring my head around "What is debain and what makes an [kernel + Rootfs + initrd] package debian?". I understand there is a Debain distribution of linux but in the world of embedded devices what does debain mean, is it the same ?. The SOC vendor provides me with option of loading a debain based system or Open embedded system or android system or Core ubuntu sytem and many more[3]. What exactly makes them all different (I understand the difference between andriod kernel and linux kernel but what about core ubuntu and debain are they not closely related)?

[1] : http://events17.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Yocto%20%2B%20Debian%20%283%29.pdf

[2] : https://www.acmesystems.it/debian_jessie

[3] : https://www.96boards.org/documentation/consumer/dragonboard410c/downloads/

Comment: I think you need to ask your product owner what they / the end client mean by "a Debian system". What we think isn't that important really.

Comment: Most probably because Debian has ports for almost all imaginable processors, something other distros can't brag about.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I am not looking for answer from the projects perspective, I am looking for answer in general. Is it just the package manger and archives and the desktop environment or there is more to it that makes a distribution debian.

Comment: And the answer to that is "depends who you ask". Some people might say Ubuntu. Mint and even Kali are "Debian". Some might not. Some people might say [Debian/kFreeBSD](https://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/) is not Debian even though it definitely is (or was), even though it doesn't use the same kernel at all.

Comment: The problem may come from the common miss use of the word Linux. Linux is just the kernel, however it is often used to mean the whole system (kernel, shell, tools, libraries, compiler, and user applications)  see here https://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.en.html it may clear up some confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may come from the common miss-use of the word Linux. Linux is just the kernel, however it is often used to mean the whole system (kernel, shell, tools, libraries, compiler, and user applications)  see here https://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.en.html it may clear up some confusion.

Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, CentOs, Suse, Vector, … are all collections of all of this. Some are related more than others.

see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#/media/File:Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg

What this does not show, is that all the projects got their material from up-stream sources. The Gnu project, A kernel named Linux, Xfree86/Xorg, and many others.